# Explicit call to Close for a db connection within a using block in C#?

Tags: c#

Is it considered bad practice to call Close for a database connection within a using block?
for example:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sConn))
{
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    // do database stuff
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: You don't need to call close since the using() block will do that upon "freeing" the object...

Comment: @kayess The `using` will dispose of the object (which in this case will close the connection).  It won't free it.  That will be done by the GC at some indeterminate point in the future.

Answer (score 10):

The [MSDN documentation for the Close method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.close(v=vs.110).aspx) already explains this.  It says (in the Remarks section):

> The Close method rolls back any pending transactions. It then releases the connection to the connection pool, or closes the connection if connection pooling is disabled.
>
> An application can call Close more than one time. No exception is generated.
>
> If the DbConnection goes out of scope, it is not closed. Therefore, you must explicitly close the connection by calling **Close or Dispose**, which are **functionally equivalent.** If the connection pooling value Pooling is set to true or yes, this also releases the physical connection.

Which means that, while it is safe to call `Close()` within the `using` block, it's not necessary.  `Dispose()` will be called when program control leaves the `using` block, which will close the connection automatically.

Comment: @Travis you should mark this as an answer to your problem/question.